Inertiajs +vitejs error using { eager: true } in import.meta.glob
I am biginner in inertiajs ecosystem. Therefore, I punctually follow the documentation of the technologies in question.
In inertiajs documentation they say: "By default we recommend eager loading your components, which will result in a single JavaScript bundle. However, if you'd like to lazy-load your components"...
Then i try to apply this recommendation in the project. Adding  {eager:true} to the import.meta.glob
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createInertiaApp, router } from '@inertiajs/react';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import '../sass/style.scss'; 

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
  title: title => `${title} - ${appName}`,
  resolve: name =>
  {
    const page = resolvePageComponent(
      `./Pages/${name}.tsx`,
      import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.tsx', { eager: true }) // here is the change,
      )
      console.log(name,import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.tsx'),{page});
    return page;
  },
  
  setup({ el, App, props }) {
    const root = createRoot(el);
    root.render(<App {...props} />);
  },
  progress: {
    color: '#F87415'
  }
});

// evento al iniciar request
router.on('start',(event)=>{
  console.log('start',{event});
  let appLoader =  document.getElementById('loader');
  appLoader?.classList.remove('hidden');
});

// evento al finalizar request
router.on('finish',(event)=>{
  console.log('finish',{event});
  let appLoader =  document.getElementById('loader');
  appLoader?.classList.add('hidden');
});


After that the application show me the error.
@vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong
With this last change the application stopped working, can someone explain to me what is wrong?
I am using laravel11, innertiajs, vitejs and react. Thanks in advance.
I try investigate following the link in the browser console but don't found answer.

What version of @vitejs/plugin-react are you using? see this

I am using "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
